# In the REDHAWK IDE when I attempt to export a waveform to the Target SDR I receive an error.

Tags: ide, redhawksdr

I am getting an error stating "Error exporting project to SDR root" when trying to export my waveform to the Target SDR.

I am using REDHAWK 1.8.3 on Centos 6 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by an ownership issue with $SDRROOT. It needs to be owned (or writeable) by the user. One option is the following:

```
$ sudo chown -R <user name>.<user name> $SDRROOT
```

The error you are referencing has been addressed in the newest documentation - http://redhawksdr.github.com/Documentation/mainch2.html.

Answer (score 0):

The option that I use is to create my own `SDRROOT` directory, then copy everything over from `/var/redhawk/sdr`.  This is a VERY GOOD THING TO DO if you have more than one person doing `Redhawk development` on the same computer or if you use different computer architectures.  I haven't used `version 1.8` yet, but in the past, if you had `SDRROOT` in your home directory and tried to use it on a computer with a different architecture (32 bit vs. 64), bad things would happen.  The fix for that is to copy over the correct binaries when you switch architectures and/or create separate 32 bit and 64 bit `SDRROOTs`...

You can also check out this [link](http://www.axiosengineering.com/redhawk/cookbook/01-installing-and-running/alternate-sdrroot.html).